# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: buildingSections

Tags: mysql, laravel, compiler-errors

Am trying to store into the database from a page I passed a variable which displayed well using @foreach without the above error but when its to be save, it gives the above error.
Here is the controller

```
$this->validate($request, array(
        'building_section' => 'required',
        'reported_date' => 'required',
        'fault' => 'required',
    ));
    $maintenance = New Maintenance();
    $maintenance->tenants_id = AssetTenant::where('tenant_id', '=', \Auth::user()->id)->first();
    $maintenance->category = AssetTenant::where('description', '=', $maintenance->tenants_id);
    $maintenance->building_section = $request->building_section;
    $maintenance->reported_date = $request->reported_date;
    $maintenance->fault = $request->fault;
    //Flash Message
    $request->session()->flash('success', 'Tenant successfully Added');
    //redirect
    return view('/tenant/addMaintenance');
```

the View

```
<select type="text" class="form-control" name="building_section" required="">
                            @foreach($buildingSections as $section)
                                <option >{{ $section->section }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
```

Note: this code works well in other section.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it's because you're returning the view rather than redirecting to that page:

change:

```
return view('/tenant/addMaintenance');
```

to:

```
return redirect('tenant/addMaintenance');
```